# Why isn't this regex stoping after the first encounter of the string its supposed to match?

Tags: java, regex, xml

I have one arxml file where I want to delete multiple elements (interfaces, ports, references of those etc).

Example :

```
<CLIENT-SERVER-INTERFACE>
    <SHORT-NAME>IF_interfaceName</SHORT-NAME>
    <IS-SERVICE>false</IS-SERVICE>
    <OPERATIONS>
        <CLIENT-SERVER-OPERATION>
            <SHORT-NAME>CS_operationname</SHORT-NAME>
            <POSSIBLE-ERROR-REFS>
                <POSSIBLE-ERROR-REF>something</POSSIBLE-ERROR-REF>
            </POSSIBLE-ERROR-REFS>
        </CLIENT-SERVER-OPERATION>

</CLIENT-SERVER-INTERFACE>
```

I'm using an array where I have stored multiple "tags" that will be replaced in my regex. ex :

```
<CLIENT-SERVER-INTERFACE(.*?)(IF_interfaceName)(.*?)</CLIENT-SERVER-INTERFACE>
```

I want to delete EVERY element that is (in this case) a client-server-interface, where my regex will match the shortname of it.

Unfortunately, if my ARXML file contains multiple elements of the same kind in a row, the regex will not stop and delete everything until the last `</client-server-interface>` it will find, even if the shortName of the other elements are not matched.

```
StringBuilder content = readArxml(filePath); // Load content from file

if (content != null) 
{ 
    // Check if content was successfully loaded
    //"tag" will iterate over an array of opening tags(<tagName>)

    for (String tag : tags) 
    {
        // "regex" will iterate over an array of regex expressions that will match the shortname tag of every element
        for (String regex : regexExp) 
        {
            String expression = "<" + tag + "(.|\\s+)*" + regex + "(.|\\s+)*" + "</" + tag + ".*>";
            String replacement = "";
            content = new StringBuilder(content.toString().replaceAll(expression, replacement));
```

What's the problem here?

I have tried to add a "?" to the expression, but that didn't work as expected , the code didn't alter the file

```
String expression = "<" + tag + "(.|\\s+)?*" + regex + "(.|\\s+)?*" + "</" + tag + ".?*>";
```

Comment: Obligatory: [**TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610)

Comment: Never use Regex on XML.  Regex is meant for regular expressions and XML is not regular.  Use an XML library.

Comment: The zalgo question is always amusing but this one is more helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg  (Seriously, do not use a regex to parse XML.)

Comment: [Java XML and JSON](https://www.amazon.com/Java-XML-JSON-Document-Processing-dp-1484243293/dp/1484243293/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) book written by Jeff Friesen